# How to confirm MacOS "system" Python version

Tags: python

MacBook Pro outfitted with Ventura 13.2.1

It is my understanding that

1. "system" python: macOS Catalina or later is deployed with Python3.x
2. removing *system* python is fatal / requires OS to be reinstalled

How does one return the version of the system Python?

I think that python@3.11 was installed by brew:

```
brew list | grep -i python   
python@3.11
```

Though I am not 100% sure.  If it is not the system python I'd like to remove it.  I'd like to avoid the fatal mistake of removing system python.

How can I be certain that:

```
brew uninstall python@3.11
```

will not remove the system python?

Comment: Hmm - is your problem you want to change the path so any python you installed on top of the system files isn’t run? Not sure why the “removing system python is fatal / requires OS to be reinstalled” statement is provided. Ventura has a sealed system, so you wither messed with that (which is quite tricky and depends on Intel vs Apple Silicon for the process to accomplish it). Are you saying you didn’t tamper with the system?

Comment: Seeking to remove python versions: I have too many version of Python installed:  `brew install hidapi` fails to import => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732954/

Comment: If you install hidapi via brew, you should also install Python via brew. Looks like your problem comes from having two partially conflicting brew versions.

Answer (score 15):

Homebrew installations are independent of macOS, you can neither update system components via Homebrew nor remove them with `brew uninstall`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title: `/usr/bin/python3 -V` will report the version of the system Python.

If you don't use `sudo` or other means to give `brew` root access, it **cannot** possibly affect any macOS components (including the system Python) unless you have changed their permissions previously, even with very old versions of macOS.

Since OS X El Capitan, there is System Integrity Protection, which means you now cannot change macOS components (including the system Python) **even with root permissions**, unless you specifically disable SIP first.

See: [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102149)

Comment: As Python is now not installed by Apple unless you install Xcode - Apple's python is not protected by SIP. First two paragraphs are correct.

Answer (score 2):

**How does one return the version of the system Python?**

```
/usr/bin/python3 -V
```

returns:

```
Python 3.9.6
```

Comment: Is your OS Ventura?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine with macOS 14.2.1 Sonoma, I found more than one python3. I'm not sure any "came with" Sonoma. First, in a terminal, `which python3` returns '/opt/homebrew/bin/python3'. I looked in /usr/bin/ and found a python3 there, too. Using `/usr/bin/python3 -h` gave me too much info but showed a path indicating it was installed with Xcode.
Here's a way to get the version: in a terminal, simply type the name of the python you want examine (this starts the python REPL - use Ctrl-D to exit). It will tell you about itself. I did that for the two pythons I found, and the one from homebrew was Python 3.11.6, and the one in /usr/bin was Python 3.9.6. If you ask homebrew to uninstall python, it will uninstall the one in its directory. Note that, at least on my system, only python3 shows up, not python or python2.

Added: Homebrew will uninstall the Python in the homebrew directory. This is not the system Python. The main point of homebrew is to add (and remove if necessary) software without messing with what the system uses. And as far as I remember, your macOS, Ventura, did not come with a system Python. Is there something else in this picture - such as another installation that depends on Python - that leads to your concern?

More: Thanks to everyone for your followup comments and corrections ;) I think my post and its comments don't need further work. I did give the OP correct information amid reproducing how I found the answers on my system, and by now others have much more succinctly addressed the main points: homebrew won't mess with system stuff; Ventura did NOT come with any "system python"; find the version of python(s) with `python3 -V`, and location path info with  `python3 -h`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.   How can I be certain that: `brew uninstall python@3.11`
will not remove the system python?

Comment: Homebrew only layers files on top of the user space. It doesn’t and can’t remove system files on your version of macOS even if it tried @gatorback

Comment: @SteveM No Ventura does not come with a system Python - you get /usr/bin/python3 you have to install Xcode

Comment: Apple removed `python` with Monterey 12.3.  If you want a `python` now, you need to install the CLT, install Xcode, or install a binary distribution.  Python.org, MacPorts, and Homebrew all make such available.

Comment: Thanks all. I summarized my post.

Comment: `python3 -h` prints the python help page

Comment: Which includes the executable's actual path info.